Set input value with Javascript don't really set the value when I send the form
This is my code
function updateName(nombreCampo, valor) {
    var campo = document.getElementsByName(nombreCampo)[0];
    campo.value = valor;
    campo.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
  }

  function updateId(nombreCampo, valor) {
    var campo = document.getElementById(nombreCampo);
    campo.value = valor;
    campo.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
  }

function updateFormData(data) {
    var listContent = data.TablaContenidos.split(", ").join("\n");
    updateName('dc.title', data.Titulo);
    updateName('dc.contributor.author', data.Autor);
    updateId('dc_date_issued_year', data.Ano);
    updateName('dc.identifier.citation', data.Citacion);
    updateName('dc.publisher', data.Publisher);
    updateName('dc.language.iso', data.Idioma);
    updateName('dc.subject.proposal', data.Palabras);
    updateName('dc.subject.ddc', data.ClasificacionDewey);
    updateName('dc.description.abstract', data.Resumen);
    updateName('dc.description', data.DescripcionRecurso);
    updateName('dc.description.tableofcontents', listContent);
    updateName('dc.relation.references', data.ReferenciasBibliograficas);
  floatingButton.innerHTML = 'Cargados - Reintentar';
  console.log('Datos actualizados.');
}

It works very well, but when I send the form the values are empty. The problem is that I only can use Javascript I can't modify the actual form logic or the html. And I can't use the form ID for some reasons.
I hope to set the values ​​with Javascript as if I manually put the values ​​in the inputs

That shouldn't happen, I've done many forms where I filled in inputs from code. Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

BTW, it's not a good idea to use . in element IDs. It's allowed, but it makes it difficult to refer to the ID using CSS selectors.

After running the function updateFormData, can you then see if the value of the input elements has been updated/changed? You need to figure out what happens when you click the submit button -- what form fields have a name attribute? Is the request done using AJAX and where are the values coming from? Is it actually a hidden form that is submitted? It is questions that we can't answer with the provided code.

@Barmar Thanks for your time sir, the problem is that I don't have the code that is because I'm programming a Google extension with that code. If you want more information, I'm programming for a dspace repository

@chrwahl Thanks for your time sir, I can't do that for the reason I have mean in the others comments

Can you add the manifest.json, and indicate which type of script this is?

@Barmar Please tell me the specific part of my manifest.json that you're interested about, and basically is an extension that get data from an API and set the values in a form on the page

I don't know. I'm not really an expert on chrome extensions, but I assume those who are would find this useful.

And it matters whether this is a content script, background script, etc.

@Barmar Thanks sir for your help, there aren't any configuration in the manifest.json that affects my script, is literally the same thing as I copy and paste code in the website console, I am only finding the form to set this information permanently with JavaScript as I do manually in the inputs

@Barmar Please if you can, vote my questions to get more visibility

Extension scripts work differently than the console. That's why it matters whether it's a content script or background scripts.

I have found the solution
function updateName(nombreCampo, valor) {
var campo = document.getElementsByName(nombreCampo)[0];
campo.value = valor;
campo.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
campo.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));}

Adding  campo.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true })) The value have been set as If I write it manually

Here is my previous code.
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('formdata', (e) => {

  const formData = e.originalEvent.formData; 
  
  formData.append('alphabet', "abcde");
  formData.append('a1b2', "123123");
});

I think it might be helpful for you.
Good luck

Hi, thanks for your time, the problem is that I'm programming a Google extension and I don't have access to the form id so I need other solution. Again thanks for your time
